# Overriding VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES

Tags: c++, cmake, vulkan

Vulkan handles are either opaque pointers to `struct`s, or simply unsigned 64-bit integers depending on the value of `VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES`:

```cpp
    #if (VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES==1)
        #define VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object) typedef struct object##_T *object;
    #else
        #define VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object) typedef uint64_t object;
    #endif
```

`VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES` is set, when not already `define`d, in `vulkan_core.h` to the following values depending on the platform (at least on my version of the header):

```cpp
#ifndef VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES
    #if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_WIN64) || (defined(__x86_64__) && !defined(__ILP32__) ) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(__ia64) || defined (_M_IA64) || defined(__aarch64__) || defined(__powerpc64__)
        #define VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES 1
    #else
        #define VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES 0
    #endif
#endif
```

The [documentation for that preprocessor `#define`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES.html) states the following:

> The `vulkan_core.h` header allows the `VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES` definition to be overridden by the application. This allows the application to select either a 64-bit pointer type or a 64-bit unsigned integer type for non-dispatchable handles in the case where the predefined preprocessor check does not identify the desired configuration.

I interpret this declaration as:

> It's okay to force `VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES`'s value at build time so that I can use either of the definitions.

But, to the best of my knowledge, changing the definitions on header-side only has... Implications for shared libraries compiled as `.dll` / `.so`, obviously including the ones of the [LunarG's Vulkan SDK](https://www.lunarg.com/vulkan-sdk/) I am using (we're not only changing *types*, we are also changing *function signatures*).

On Linux or on Windows with MinGW, `VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES` is `1` by default. On Windows using MSVC, it defaults to `0`. So I tried changing it to `1`, which, as expected, generates the following linker error (MRE used for that test below).

> `main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vkCmdBindIndexBuffer@20 referenced in function "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YAXXZ)`
> `vk_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

**Edit -** clarification after comment: everything is `extern "C"{}` in `vulkan_core.h`.

---

I highly, *highly* doubt the Vulkan documentation is wrong, so I assume I must be missing something very obvious.
I suspect the answer is either:

- "It's just you're not linking with the correct target after overriding that value"
- "You're misinterpreting what the docs says. 'application' here does not refer to what you think it does"

But I don't really know how to confirm my conjunctures.

---

#### MRE:

##### `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

project(vk_test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

add_executable(vk_test main.cpp)

# No effect for GCC / MinGW
# On MSVC on the other hand, the value is set to 0 when not defined by user
# Comment that line to build with MSVC
add_compile_definitions(VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES=1)

target_link_libraries(vk_test PUBLIC ${Vulkan_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(vk_test SYSTEM PUBLIC ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

##### `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <cassert>

#include <vulkan/vulkan_core.h>

void foo()
{
    assert(false); // The following call has invalid parameters, so no point letting execution reach that point
    vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(VK_NULL_HANDLE, VK_NULL_HANDLE, 0, VkIndexType{});
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**System**:

- Windows 10.
- MSVC: ver. 19 ~ `14.34` (hopefully got their numbering correct)
- Vulkan SDK ver. `1.3.216.0`.

Comment: Is `vkCmdBindIndexBuffer` (and everything else in the Vulkan header files) declared `extern "C"`?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes indeed. Sorry, I should have added that to the question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, just a little bit more research allowed me to clear things up.

**TL;DR:** it's not meant to be used like that (so I was *partially* right in my conjunctures, yay!). Overriding `VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES` makes it so you cannot use the "raw" definitions of the lib' you're linking with for, well, the reasons I was worried about in my post.
Instead, you first create a `VkInstance`, and ***then*** get the function pointers using `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` (resp. with a `VkDevice` and `vkGetDeviceProcAddr` for device functions). All the functions required to get the relevant function pointers are accessible from the lib'.

---

A simple demo of what you are expected to do when overriding `VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

project(vk_test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

add_executable(vk_test main.cpp)

# No effect for GCC / MinGW
# On MSVC on the other hand, the value is set to 0 when not defined by user
add_compile_definitions(VK_USE_64_BIT_PTR_DEFINES=1)

target_link_libraries(vk_test PUBLIC ${Vulkan_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(vk_test SYSTEM PUBLIC ${Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <vulkan/vulkan_core.h>

void foo()
{
    const VkInstanceCreateInfo instance_info
    {
        /*.sType                   = */VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO,
        /*.pNext                   = */nullptr,
        /*.flags                   = */0,
        /*.pApplicationInfo        = */nullptr,
        /*.enabledLayerCount       = */0,
        /*.ppEnabledLayerNames     = */nullptr,
        /*.enabledExtensionCount   = */0,
        /*.ppEnabledExtensionNames = */nullptr
    };

    VkInstance instance = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    if(vkCreateInstance(&instance_info, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << ":(" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    const auto f = reinterpret_cast<PFN_vkCmdBindIndexBuffer>(vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCmdBindIndexBuffer"));
    std::cout << (f != nullptr) << std::endl; // Prints '1' (hopefully for you too)

    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
}

int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

---

##### Alternatives / tools to avoid having to write such code yourself

- There is a generated list of all the required calls in [`vulkan.hpp`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp/blob/c8cf030fe9a00493ff854910000c23ab645cc490/vulkan/vulkan.hpp#L15411), which hopefully can be integrated in your application with less efforts than writing this by hand.
- [`Vulkan-Loader` (VOLK)](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader) is a Khronos-developed library for that purpose. It also has a [list](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/master/vulkan.symbols.api) of the symbols that can be loaded in such a way stored as plain text, which can also be used to generate appropriate code.

Comment: Yuk, that's _horrible_.  There has to be a better way; maybe you can find it.  Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=msvc-170) (you want the section entitled "Format of a C decorated name").  I would say the Vulkan guys have left the job half done here.

Comment: But +1 anyway :)

Comment: @PaulSanders Actually, considering how common is `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` in Vulkan (it's called for similar purpose for each function in extensions, which gave me the epiphany to write this answer), perhaps that *may* be considered """elegant""" in a certain way as it provides *at least* something homogenous and coherent in the API. But that's going to make me write (or generate actually) code I did not really wanted to `:(`

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't want to have to do it that way either.  Too much chance of a spelling mistake!

Comment: Also, I forgot about [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp)

Comment: @PaulSanders They fortunately have a generated list of the required calls for `vkGetInstanceProcAddr`. If I remember correctly there were some problems on some very specific platforms where commonly available extensions aren't (so missing `VK_EXT_blabla`  define`s are missing), but that was long ago so these were probably fixed (or I may be completely misremembering or mixing things up with something else). 
I don't really like `vulkan-hpp` because it makes compilation time go wild, but this sequence of calls for core functions are indeed very useful. I update my answer with a link to this.